# Undefined function or variable 'fplot3' in MATLAB R2015a

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Although I installed all the toolbox in MATLAB R2015a, encounter "Undefined function or variable `fplot3`" error after running the script below as on [Plot 3-D Parametric Line](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fplot3.html).

```
syms t
xt = sin(t);
yt = cos(t);
zt = t;
fplot3(xt,yt,zt)
```

Any idea to fix the problem?

Comment: `fplot3` was introduced in MATLAB R2016a

Comment: Thanks a lot. What about MATLAB R2015a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mentioned in the documentation that [**`fplot3`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fplot3.html) was introduced in **MATLAB R2016a**. Since you're using an older version of MATLAB and hence, as the error says, *it is an undefined function*.

For older versions, the same can be achieved by [**`ezplot3`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ezplot3.html). Just replace `fplot3` with `ezplot3` in your code.

The code written in the question gives the following output in MATLAB 2016a and newer versions:

[image: output_fplot3]

Replacing `fplot3` with `ezplot3` in that code gives this:

[image: output_ezplot3.1]

This output is correct. However to get the same output as that of `fplot3`, you can adjust the domain of plot as: `ezplot3(xt,yt,zt,[-5,5])` which gives exactly the same output as shown below:

[image: output_ezplot3.2]

Comment: On the other hand, I have a look at the Documentation on https://www.mathworks.com/help/ but it only contains the latest version. As I use version R2015a, I tried to reach the documenttion for this version but it requires license. But I have student license and it does not permit. Anyway, is there a documentation that does not ask license, etc?

Comment: @ClintEastwood You can access the documentation related to your version using `doc (function_name)` in the command window. e.g. `doc ezplot3`. Another option is: `help ezplot3`. Or simply writing `doc` opens a window which lets you to choose the topic you want

Comment: That means I can use Help context in order to reach the documentation for the release I use, is that correct?

Comment: Yes ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Voted++ :)

Comment: @ClintEastwood for previous docs online go here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html

Comment: @EBH it requires licence and thus he cannot use it as he stated in his previous comments

Comment: Well, you right. I never noticed I need a licence for this.

Comment: @Sardar_Usama What about the question on [Plotting Electromagnetic Wave in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492438/plotting-electromagnetic-wave-in-matlab)? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @EBH What about [Plotting Electromagnetic Wave in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492438/plotting-electromagnetic-wave-in-matlab)? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @ClintEastwood, sorry, but I don't understand your question there (and I saw it before you pinged me, so  there's no need in this).